# Apple M1 MacBooks custom screen resolution - HiDPI

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook

Recently I have bought the Apple M1 Macbook Pro.
I am using it with 2K Dell monitor. However, it runs in native resolution `2560 x 1440`, and everything is so small. Changing the resolution to `1920 x 1080` will solve the issue with small texts, however, everything is blurry.

The `SwitchresX` application could solve my issue, however, the M1 processor is not supported right now.

Any workarounds for this?

I would like to use lower resolution without blurring, or 1280 x 720 @2x HiDPI.

Comment: Related question: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/m1-mac-mini-wont-recognize-manual-hidpi-settings.2273289/?post=29346187#post-29346187

Comment: Another related question: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668252

Answer (score 0):

You can use BetterDummy to solve the issue of 2K displays on M1 macs (including the Mini).

https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDummy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).